# How can I enable distributed transactions for a AWS RDS linked server?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2008, rds

I have a SQL Server 2008 RDS instance, which i created a linked server(AWSMSSQL) on my local machine SQL server 2014.

Now i create a trigger for insert, update and delete from my local machine database table

```
USE [test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ms_test] ON [dbo].[localservertable]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    declare @iddata int;
    declare @option int;

    select @iddata=i.[id] from inserted i;
    select @option=i.[option] from inserted i;          

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        select @option=d.[option] from deleted d;
        DELETE FROM [AWSMSSQL].[test].[dbo].[localservertable] WHERE [option]=@option;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [AWSMSSQL].[test].[dbo].[localservertable] VALUES (@iddata,@option);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [AWSMSSQL].[test].[dbo].[localservertable] SET [option]=9 WHERE id=1;
        END 
    END
END;
```

when i update on local database table, using code

```
UPDATE [dbo].[localservertable]
   SET [option] = 5
 WHERE [iddata]=1
```

It shows an error

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "AWSMSSQL" returned message "The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".
Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ms_item, Line 29
The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "AWSMSSQL" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.
```

I found this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731005(v=ws.10)) which told me how to modify the settings for the MSDTC. But after changes made i restart AWS RDS SERVER and local machine. But same error will existing. Help me out of this error

[image]

[image]

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi all, Distributed transactions not needed for functions. So i used user defined functions update, insert, delete inside the trigger. [Reference](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12585/invalid-use-of-a-side-effecting-operator-insert-within-a-function-multiple-i)

Answer (score 1):

Triggers implicitly have [XACT_ABORT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on. An error with this setting on will automatically lead to transaction rollback (except for errors raised in the code with the RAISERROR statement).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at present distributed transactions are not supported on RDS.

Comment: RDS is basically "SQL Server for kids".  Of course it doesn't support something as critical as distributed transactions. Indeed, it's listed under "Features Not Supported and Features with Limited Support": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html

Everything in AWS is crippled and raw, and requires an entire team of people to manage. This is why Azure was created. No problem with distributed transactions there. Eventually, we'll need systems like Google Cloud Spanner that support true ACID-compliant distributed transactions in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Distributed transactions are now supported on RDS for SQL Server - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-rds-for-sql-server-now-supports-distributed-transactions/

Answer (score 0):

Distributed transactions are now supported in RDS for SQL Server. A guide how to configure MSDTC is described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/enabling-distributed-transaction-support-for-domain-joined-amazon-rds-for-sql-server-instances/). Full documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.MSDTC.html).